# CartoDB - How do I turn on a scale (in feet / imperial) in the Visualization?

Tags: carto, scale

I'm making a map for an architectural site analysis and need to have a scale for the Visualization. Is this a feature in CartoDB?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a built in feature, but you can follow this example in which the scale is built with Leaflet:

http://bl.ocks.org/xavijam/8433314